# Language switcher doesn't switch to the correct language view

Tags: views

I am using Drupal 7 and have built views with two languages. I can display the English view normally but when I click on the link of the other language on the language switcher the view only switches direction to the right without changing to the translated view. All the needed core modules enabled, I also installed the i18n latest version module. As for normal pages, everything works perfect. I have tried using the filter (content language) with no results. I have googled the issue and got some solutions that has given no fruitful results. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Did you create separate views pages or use the same one?

Comment: I created separate views pages: For example for the English I created a view (seminars_en) and created a page view. After that I created another view (Seminars_ar) and then created a page view. Both views using taxonomy. Do u want more info? Thanks.

Comment: here is the url http://novalifeiraq.com